# android google analytics doesn't show compaign sources

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-firebase

we are trying to [Testing Google Play Campaign Measurement](https://developers.google.com/analytics/solutions/testing-play-campaigns#prepare)
but in web interface there is no "test_source" appeared

console shows this

```
V/GAv4    (19277): CampaignTrackingReceiver received: com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER
    V/GAv4    (19277): CampaignTrackingService is starting up
    V/GAv4    (19277): CampaignTrackingService called. startId, campaign: 1, utm_source=test_source&utm_campaign=test_name
    V/GAv4    (19277): AnalyticsService registered in the app manifest and enabled
    D/GAv4    (19277): Received installation campaign: name=test_name, source=test_source
    V/GAv4    (19277): Install campaign broadcast processed: true
    V/GAv4    (19277): CampaignTrackingService is shutting down
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @Flummox we are trying to
[Test Google Play Campaign Measurement](https://developers.google.com/analytics/solutions/testing-play-campaigns#prepare)

Comment: Please include in Question.